# What is the correct way to attempt this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Determine the value of: $$(1^2+3^2+5^2+...+99^2)-(2^2+4^2+6^2+...+100^2)+(4+8+12+...+200)$$

**Attempt**

I can see that the first 2 series are neither arithmetic nor geometric, however when I used the equation for an arithmetic series, I got the right answer (50).

My teacher told the class a hint: look at the first term of each bracket together, then the second term of each bracket, and so on. I don’t understand why we need to do this and although I know that the way I solved the problem was incorrect, I can’t think of any other way to solve it.

Comment: What is the pattern for $2^2 +4^2 + 6 +2 + .... + 100$?  Was that supposed to be $2^2 + 4^2 + 6^2 + .... + 100$?

Comment: "however when I used the equation for an arithmetic series, I got the right answer "  What did you do about the first two series?  Ignore them? " I know that the way I solved the problem was incorrect" It'd help if you told us *how* you solved it.  We have no idea what you did, so we have no idea if it was correct or not.

Comment: " I don’t understand why we need to do this "  Well, if you *tried* it you would have seen.  $(1^2 - 2^2 + 4) + (3^2 - 4^2 + 8) + (5^2 - 6^2 + 12)+ ....$   what is $1^2 -2^2 + 4$?  What is $3^2 -4^2 + 8$?  Etc.  Can you see why that might be?

Answer (score 4):

$$1^2 -2^2 +4= (1-2)(1+2) +4 = -3 +4 =1 \\
3^2 - 4^2 + 8 = (3-4)(3+4)+8 = -7 + 8 =1$$
See the pattern?

The key to this (and a lot of problems like this) is $n^2 - m^2 = (n-m)(n+m)$. It's also just a really helpful identity in general.

Answer (score 2):

So I think the hint is to rearrange the expression as

> $$
>     (1^2-2^2)+(3^2-4^2)+\dots+(99^2-100^2) + 4(1 + 2 + \dots + 50)
> $$

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

$(1^2 + 3^2 + ... + 99^2) = \sum_{k=1}^{50} (2k-1)^2$

$(2^2 + 4^2  + .... + 100^2) = \sum_{k=1}^{50} (2k)^2$

$(4 + 8 + ..... + 200) = \sum_{k=1}^{50} 4*k$

So $(1^2 + 3^2 + ... + 99^2)-(2^2 + 4^2  + .... + 100^2)+(4 + 8 + ..... + 200) =$

$\sum_{k=1}^{50}[ (2k-1)^2 - (2k)^2+ 4*k] =$

$\sum_{k=1}^{50}[( 4k^2 - 4k + 1) -4k^2 + 4*k] =$

$\sum_{k=1}^{50}1 = 50$.

That's it!

Let try a few.

$1^2 - 2^2 + 4 = 1$

And $3^2 - 4^2 + 8 = 1$

And $5^2 - 6^2 + 12 = 1$ and ... interesting.

But $7^2 - 8^2 + 16 = (7-8)(7+8) + 16 = -15 + 16 = 1$ or

$(k-1)^2 + k^2 + 2k = ((k-1) -k)((k-1) + k) + 2k = -(2k -1) + 2k = 1$.

Lot's of ways to do it but $(2k-1)^2 + (2k)^2 + 4k = 1$.  Always.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who replied, it was very helpful! :)